# PHP separate domain and local folder from request uri

Tags: php

I Separate domain name with parse url like this in `localhost/test/news/id/title` :

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $parts;
```

Ouput is:

```
/test/news/id/title
```

Now `test` is folder of xampp htdocs and is not a folder in my app folder structures.

In action I need to separate `domain` and `htdocs` folder If I work in localhost And separate domain if I work in real web address like this output:

`/news/id/title`

How do can I print this output?

Answer (score 2):

You should set up the `DocumentRoot` of your projects.

If working on a localhost project I use the following Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.loc
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project"

  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

  <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/project>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This setup would have `C:/xampp/htdocs/project` be the `host` result instead of `htdocs`.

If you combine this with updating your Windows "hosts" file (here: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) then you can access the project with this config using `http://project.loc`.

Add the following line to the "hosts" file (use Notepad++ in Administrator mode to save this in Windows folder):

```
127.0.0.1       project.loc
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure PHP you also can do it this little "dirty" way:

```
list($rubish,$path)=explode('/','/'.$parts,2);
```

Now you var $path will show /news/id/title on echo.

Let me explain the Code:
explode() will split the $parts string in 2 slices.
The list() function define that the first part is saved in $rubish (the /test/ part) and the second part $path will get the rest of you path ;-)

> But i also prefer what @rkeet answered!